# Shibboleth IdP - allow users to choose password or SAML login flow

Tags: saml, shibboleth, idp

I have implemented a shibboleth idp (`myidp.example.com`) on my own server with password flow. They authenticate with their username and password against database MySQL.

At this point, everything is fine.

But now I want to add one more login flow: SAML. I want to allow users to choose either login in by username/password or through another idp (`idp.anotherwebsite.com`). It's up to them to choose which method to login.

I've read through the entire shibboleth wiki, but it seems none of the articles mentions about my use case.
Can someone point me some direction?

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented one idp.

Now for authentication page, you might need to implement one SP.

This is a normal usecase. Search for Federeted login.

Softwares like [KeyCloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) may help as well